# Check for excel attachments in email received in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, vba, macros

What I'm trying to accomplish with the code below is to create a macro that checks all unread emails in a Outlook folder with an excel attachment. After that I want it to run another macro that I created in excel. The problem that I have is that with the code below I keep getting Run-time error

> '424': Object required.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

```
Sub attach()
Dim myNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlWB2 As Object
Const File_Path As String = ""

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Reports")

On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
xlApp.Visible = True

For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
    If InStr(myAttachment.DisplayName, "Detail") > 0 Then
        myAttachment.SaveAsFile File_Path & myAttachment.FileName
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(File_Path & myAttachment.FileName)
    End If
Next myAttachment

xlWB2.Application.Run "ExportToPDF"

End Sub
```

I get the error message when I reach the following part:

> For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments

Comment: Where do you get this error message

Comment: I get the error message when I reach the following part:                              'For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments'

Comment: I suggest you  add `option explicit` to the top of the file. Also add the `myItem.Attachments` to the watch list. Are there any attachments?

Comment: Also you should edit your post to include the extra detail. I've done it for you this time

Comment: In the folder that I want the code to look I have a few emails that have excel attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myItem` object does not exist.

```
Set myUnreadItems = myFolder.items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")

If myUnreadItems.count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No unread mail in: " & myFolder
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = myUnreadItems.count To 1 Step -1     
    Set myItem = myUnreadItems(i)
```